# Forcing Git to use a specific .gitconfig file

Tags: windows, git, environment-variables, git-config

I have tried to google this but could not find a solution.

Context:
My work laptop constantly keeps changing my `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables.
Instead of trying other approaches to [change those variables](https://superuser.com/questions/255776/overriding-homedrive-and-homepath-as-a-windows-7-user)  on my system, I was trying to see if I can force Git to use a `.gitconfig` file of my choice.

So far I have had no success. Is it possible?

**Update**:

Based on VonC's response below, please note that these variables can't be edited under Environment variables section. I think it's set by active directory policy. I have tried it.

Comment: You can edit your user environment variable: add HOME and you are set.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change your `%HOME%` **user** environment variable.

Git will use any `.gitconfig` found in `%HOME%`.
If `HOME` is not defined, then it is made from `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.

Comment: Already tried it. These variables are set by AD, I can't see or change them in environment variables. Also please note that HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH variables can't be edited; may be this is how active directory works.

Comment: @Ayusman you can define HOME at anytime in your **user** environment variable or in your current CMD session: `set HOME=...`. Try it: it works.